# CSS div width overhang when hovered

Tags: html, css, hover

So I have created a div, put a word in it, added some styling, and then when I hover it I want something to happen. However, the div's 'hitbox' if you like overhangs to the right.

Here is an example of what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/n83y3rvw/2/

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="word">
        WORD
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#word {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 80px;
font-size: 36px;
letter-spacing: 30px;
color: black;
font-weight: 400;
background-color: red;
/* width: 202px; */
}
#word:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

When the code is executed, you can clearly see the width of the div extending past the word in the div.

But, even when I reduce the width of the div to '202px' - the width of the word - the 'hitbox' of the div is still there and you can still trigger the background-color change even when you're not hovering over the word.

I've tried wrapping the word inside the div element in paragraph tags and then saying when hovering over the paragraph tags the background-color should change, but this didn't work. :(

What changes do I need to make to amend this?

Cheers!

Comment: Do you want the text centered ? What is the end result you're looking for ?

Comment: What do you expect the letter-spacing property to do?

Comment: The div:hover to be only triggered when the text inside the div is hovered. So is there a way to get rid of the div overhang?

Comment: The letter-spacing is just some styling i want

Comment: I have just see your example on fiddle, but the only thing I see is the color chage when I hover the div. So I can not quite understand what you are trying to do. Please be kind and explain it to me.

Comment: Unless I don't understand what you mean by "overhang", the letter-spacing is causing it.

Comment: Ok, so my problem is there is a width overhang on the right, so the div extends past the width of the text inside. This causes the div:hover to be triggered even when the mouse isn't over the text, consequently, div:hover could be triggered if the mouse was hovering just to the right of the text. I want to get rid of the div overhang, but when I reduced the width of the div to 202px, even though the overhang was not visible, it was still there.

Comment: Oh, ok, so if the letter-spacing is causing it, should I just wrap the last letter with a span and give it a letter-spaciing of 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution can be seen here: [jsfiddle.net/n83y3rvw/](//jsfiddle.net/n83y3rvw/)

It involves wrapping the last letter in its own class and giving it `letter-spacing: 0;` and applying `white-space: nowrap;` to the container `div`.

Comment: Thanks, I just released this a second ago and typed it as a comment lol Did you just copy what I said as an answer lol? Also, I think your link is wrong

Comment: No, was my own solution but my js fiddle link was wonky so I temporarily took it down to correct it. Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

The extra white space after "D" is a result of your letter-spacing: 30px; style. If you want space in between your letters you could type it into your HTML like :

```
W&nbsp;O&nbsp;R&nbsp;D
```

W O R D

each `&nbsp;` is one space so you could also do

```
W&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;O&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;R&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;D
```

W   O   R   D

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm looking for specific letter spacing, and typing that out so many times is a bit tedious

Comment: In that case I would go with the other solution people have provided of wrapping the last letter in its own span tag.